# Contact form error PHP

Tags: php

Trying to write a contact form script only my following page isnt processing...

```
<?php 

$rpname = $_POST['name'];
$rpnumber = $_POST['phone'];

echo $rpname;
echo $rpnumber;

$rpname = $_POST['name'];
$rpnumber = $_POST['phone'];
$to = "liam@.co.uk"; // CHANGE THIS TO EMAIL YOU WANT
$subject = "Phonecall Request"

//begin of HTML message
$message = "
  Phone call request - 
  From : $rpname,
  Number: $rpnumber 
";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn";
    $headers  .= "From: Website Enquiry";



if (isset($rpname))
{
       // now lets send the email.
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   $page='index.html';
header('Location:'.$page);
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?e=Message Sent!');

} ?>
```

Ive tried to echo the variables at the top but im getting a blank page with no source...

Comment: Add this at the start of the script and report back the errors which you get
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: also try print_r($_POST); at the top, to print out the post array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a semicolon (;) after `$subject = "Phonecall Request"`.

You would have caught this error yourself if your configuration had error reporting enabled. Do this is in your `php.ini` file. This will most likely be located in `/etc/php5/cgi/`. Add the following lines:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

If you don't have access to this on your server, you can add it on a per-document basis, by including the following line at the beginning of each PHP document:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Nice catch, but you should also mention he should enable error displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a copy error on that lines:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn";
$headers .= "From: Website Enquiry";
```

it should be this:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Website Enquiry";
```

The `rn` makes no sense exept you want `\r\n` which is a linebreak.

Comment: That would indeed be a problem, but it won't cause the error the OP described.